# How to return Java Set object to webflowc state

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am new to spring web flow , my requirement is return a set object to spring web flow action state by evaluating an expression .I am facing problem with below code please correct me.

```
<action-state id="openDocument">    
<set name="requestScope.startPoint" value="requestParameters.startPoint"  />
<set name="requestScope.fileName" value="requestParameters.fileName"  />
 <set name="requestScope.ext" value="requestParameters.ext"  />   
<evaluate expression="workflowController.workflowopenFile(requestScope.startPoint,requestScope.fileName,requestScope.ext)"></evaluate>
</action-state>
```

Comment: You want to put the return value of `workflowController.workflowopenFile()` into a variable in the flow?

Answer (score 0):

return the expected object from workflowopenFile() , and set it to a variable in flow with result attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. the problem was in

add return attribute to evaluate tag . (`result = "workflowSet"`).